# How can I pass a existed txt file into a function?

Tags: python

So I already have a text.txt file contain with something like:

```
This is my file
for my exercise
and i need pass this file
into a function
```

And at first i need to pass it into a function we can say like `functionForFile()` so i can working on this file. But I have no idea how to do it. Please give me some advices

Comment: Do you need to pass the text of the file to the function?

Comment: Please do your own research on topics like this. One google search and you get more than enough results. one of them: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```py
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    text = f.read()

functionForFile(text)
```

Comment: you assume that the OP needs the full content but you do not know

Comment: Yes, this was my assumption, but I can refine the solution if I have more information

Comment: yep, the question needs details

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
f = open("your-text-file.txt")
content = f.read()
f.close()
```

that way you get the content of the file

Answer (score 0):

you can pass only the path and then play with the object file inside the function:

```
functionForFile(file_path)
```

if you want to pass only the object file you can do:

```
of = open(<file_path>, 'r')
functionForFile(of)
```